# How to show multiple featured image in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I used this ***dynamic featured image*** plugin of WP, when I using this plugin it shows all the images what I uploaded.

But I just want to view only one image in this array.

I try this, but doesn't work:

```
 if( class_exists('Dynamic_Featured_Image') ) {
global $dynamic_featured_image;

$featured_images = $dynamic_featured_image->get_featured_images( );
//print_r($featured_images);

//You can now loop through the image to display them as required
foreach($featured_images as $featured_image) {
    echo "<img src='".$featured_image[1]['full']."'></a>";
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Multiple Featured wordpress plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/multiple-featured-images/#installation)

You have to add this plugin

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a foreach loop, just grab the image using the array index you want:

```
if( class_exists('Dynamic_Featured_Image') ) {

    global $dynamic_featured_image;

    $featured_images = $dynamic_featured_image->get_featured_images( );
    //print_r($featured_images);

    //you don't need to loop through anything, just use the array index
    echo "<img src='".$featured_images[1]['full']."'></a>";

}
```